# How to decode base64 for both Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, command-line, macos, base64

On Linux I can do:

```bash
echo ${ANDROID_KEYSTORE} | base64 -di > android/keystores/staging.keystore
```

But on macOS, the same commands give:

```bash
base64: option requires an argument -- i
Usage:  base64 [-hvDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

I have tried to replace `-di` with `--decode --input`, but it didn't help.

1. How do I fix the macOS command?
2. Is there a command that works both on Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) and macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want portability, you'll have to implement the linux-flavour's `-i` yourself

```bash
# don't forget to quote the variable!
echo "${ANDROID_KEYSTORE}" \
| sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]//g' \
| base64 -d
```

The sed command drops [invalid characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648)

Comment: This is great answer! Thanks

Comment: Also, MacOS `base64` uses `-D`, not `-d`

Comment: @tripleee It uses `-d`, `-D`, and `--decode` and they all mean the same thing.

Comment: Potentially quicker alternative to the `sed` command: `tr -d 'A-Z0-9+/='`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Hmmm, thanks. I had to unlearn `-d` when I got a Mac but I guess it has acquired this option synonym since then.